# How to add an object to an object of objects in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im working in Mongodb via mongoose and I have an document structured like this

```
information : {
  route : {
    point : {
      longitude: whatever,
      latitude: whatever_else
    },
    point : {
      longitude: whatever_2,
      latitude: whatever_else_2
    },
    .
    .
    .
    point : {
      longitude: whatever_N,
      latitude: whatever_else_N
    },
    // How do I insert another 'point' object right here using mongoose?
  }
}
```

I am structuring it like this because of an article I read about resizing large arrays in Mongodb https://morpheusdata.com/blog/2014-12-01-how-to-store-large-lists-in-mongodb

I expect this particular route object to become pretty large pretty quickly and i felt that this would be a good approach to speed up interactions with the object in general. However I am running into an issue where normally if this were an array of object i would be able to push any new 'point' objects onto the end of the array, but since it is structured as an object of objects i am not sure how to add any new objects with the same key: 'point' without overwriting the object already present

Comment: Hm.. what you built is not the same as what the author did. `{ p: 1, p: 2 }` is the same as `{ p: 2 }`. The author uses different keys, whereas you are not.

Comment: I could implement different keys but  the keys don't mean anything to the application I'm working on, I could incrememnet each on I suppose but then I need to bring the object down into memory again which is what I was trying to avoid

Comment: In json a key is unique. Either you start use different key, either the way you store the data is unadapted to what you need and you should consider storing each key in a different document.